# Anyone know how to add a .obj model into a minecraft mod?

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

This is a minecraft forge(1.12) development question.

I made a obj model which include .mtl and .png files
but I can't apply this model into minecraft game.

[This is item define](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WEOg.png)

[json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9WSf.png)